# How do I query relations using parse.com pointers

Tags: android, pointers, parse-platform

I have a post and a comment classes and activities on my app.I am trying to query a comment object that has a pointer `parent<postId>` to the post object.
The pointer is the objectid of a post object.On the comment activity,when user clicks a post button, the relations is created.

```
Comments comments = new Comments();
comments.put("parent",ParseObject.createWithoutData("post",postId));
```

When I try to query the comment object like

```
ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Comments>factory= new ParseObjectAdapter.QueryFactory<Comments>(){
    ParseQuery<Comments>query =Comments.getquery();
    query.whereEqualTo("parent",postId);
    query.include ("user");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Comments>(){ 
        @Override 
        public void done(List<Comments>list,ParseException e){ 
            if (e!=null){if(Application.APPDEBUG){
                Log.d(Application.APPTAG,"Error ",e);
            }
            return;
        }}); 
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt"); 
    return query;
}};
```

I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. How do I query related parse Objects?

Comment: Where do you get the NullPointerException? Can you post your log?

Comment: Why are you doing a findInBackground inside of that adapter?